# Gradle builds with parameters

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I need an instance of my server to run integration test against. In most cases I need to start an instance before tests and to stop it after. But when I develop the tests, it is more convenient to run the instance once or use a developer instance. So I need to configure different tasks depending on what I want this time.

I can use gradle command line parameters to customise build but there is no possibility to set parameters using Idea and Gradle panel or using green button from a test file.

Is there some way to have some dropdown menu in Idea switching parameters of gradle run or some other convenient way to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you looked at Run -> Edit Configurations? Can fine tune in there

Comment: Yes, but... It is hard to create configurations for all possible needs. Everybody in the team should create there own configurations, and Idea cannot help, even worse, it says that some configuration are invalid because there is no some tasks in the default configuration which is used by Idea. And finally if some test is failed, there is no way to rerun it.